# Array of 2D Array's dynamic allocated

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I need an Array := arr of 2D Arrays := multi_arr whereas the 2D Arrays have a fixed size which is 9x9 for instance. The size of arr can vary thus needs to be reallocated when the buffer is not needed. How do I instantiate the Pointer for my purpose? I tried something like this

`int (*grid_ptr)[N][N] = malloc(sizeof(int) * buffer); // buffer is the size of multi_arrs`

How do I add a 2D array here? I need some sort of list so I could do

`grid_ptr[0] = grid;` which doesnt work.

I also want to pass multi_arrs as a parameter in a function and add Elements to the list in a function via reference. I suppose I cannot read the size of filled elements in the array/list so I need to count any inserts to arr with a variable.

What I want is something like this in pseudocode

```
int* getGrids(int* sizeOfGrid)
{
    InitializeArray(int *grid);
    while(condition){
         doSomethingWithGrid(grid[0],&grid,&gridCount); // I pass the first Grid, 
                                                      // get the whole Grid and Length by reference                      
                                                      // I want to add elements to arr and read values 
                                                      //  of multi_arr 2D array to the 
                                                      //  grid in the function
         

    }
    free(grid);
}
```

Comment: The second question is entirely unclear.

Comment: Fixed size, fixed at compile time (`struct grid { int cell[N][N]; };` possible), or set at runtime (`unsigned N=0; scanf("%u", &N);` or something)?

Comment: If you can use a struct, your life will be a lot simpler.

Comment: Consider using `malloc(n_arrays * sizeof *grid_ptr);`. It is both simpler and less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays do not have the assignment operator.

You can use standard C string function `memcpy` as for example

```
memcpy( grid_ptr[0], grid, sizeof( grid ) );
```

grid must be an array to be correct to use sizeof( grid ). Otherwise you need to use some variable that stores the size of the array pointed to by the pointer grid.

Comment: Consider adding a note that `grid` must be an array, not a pointer

Comment: @tstanisl grid can be a pointer. What is the problem?

Comment: `sizeof( grid )`

Comment: @tstanisl Oh, you are right.:)